# android -how to use getSupportActionBar in another java file

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to use my custom actionbar for different activities .I've a func.java file and this is the code I've in this file :

```
public void Actionbar_Custom( Activity act,Context ctx ){
    ActionBar actionBar = act.getSupportActionBar();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View mCustomView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);

    ImageView nDrawer = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    nDrawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DrawerActivity.open();
        }
    });

    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setIcon(null);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF4548")));
    actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);

    Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) mCustomView.getParent();
    parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
}
```

The first line , getSupportActionBar(); has an error : cannot resolve method "getSupportActionbar"

How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: What is the import of your actionBar?

Comment: try getActionBar() or if in a fragment try getActivity().getActionBar()

Comment: show activity `onCreate()` and what parent class of this activity?

Comment: Your class needs to extend from ActionBarActivity, rather than a plain Activity in order to use the getSupport*() methods.

Comment: everyone , This is not in an activity class, this is in a java file that extends nothing and it doesn't have any layout . I just want to use this class in different activities and I don't want to copy and paste it in every activity